# How do sites like Shopify And Squarespace automate reverse proxy configuration when setting up custom domains?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a multitenant site separated by subdomains. Every user on my site has their own subdomain. This is the same pattern that is used by sites like shopify, squarespace, etc:

```
mary.marketplacesite.com
matt.marketplacesite.com
john.marketplacesite.com
```

Users also have an option to use their custom domain by providing an A and CNAME record to my reverse proxy server (sites.marketplacesite.com). Shopify/Squarespace have the same exact instructions:

https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205812378-Connecting-a-domain-to-your-Squarespace-site#toc-step-5---add-the-first-cname-record

https://help.shopify.com/manual/domains/connecting-existing-domains/setting-up-your-domain

After this is done, I have to manually add the site to the conf file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.mary.com mary.com;
  location / {
    access_log off;
    proxy_pass http://mary.marketplacesite.com;
  }
}
```

This all works, but is this really what Shopify/Squarespace does for thousands of sites? How do they automatically update the proxy server configuration? Is there a better approach?

Do I have to create a **server block** for each custom domain? or to have an script that generates that .conf file and store it in "/etc/nginx/conf.d/"?.
I also heard that there is Nginx+, but there is a cheaper way to do it?

Comment: Also interested in these setups. I do believe they use a way to automatically generate SSL certs like Traefik does based on config files but more fine-grained.  And that they use their web app server or container where sites arrive post load balancer with specific cname for that server to load date for client cname which can be used as a filter.

Comment: I imagine they would probably automatedly add DNS rules and create a directory on a server with each new domain then use fixed regexes as nginx rules that work for any domain. Just a guess.

Comment: Hello, did you managed to find out how to do it properly ?